# What is the proper way to deal with adding/deleting many-to-many relationships in REST?

Tags: web-services, http, rest, many-to-many

Let's say we have an entity that contains a list of users on the server, and we want to expose this as rest. What is the proper way to do it?

My first guess is something like this:

```
/entity/1/user/5
```

We can use PUT for updates and DELETE for deletes?

Is this right? I went to wikipedia where it talks about rest, and their view of it is that everything is only 1 level deep. So maybe they want you to use PUT/POST and give the entire JSON graph and update the entire thing all at once?

Comment: what do you mean by entitiy , is this is the rest api >>https://graph.facebook.com/19292868552

Comment: @Rahul Mehta: entity as in a business object, like "hotel", "club", "question", etc.

Comment: you could try something like OData http://www.odata.org/developers/protocols/json-format#RepresentingCollectionsOfEntries

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your example is a perfectly valid approach.
However in many cases a `User` can exist outside of the context of just `entity`.  I tend to identify resources in isolation, e.g:

```
/entity/1
/user/5
```

To see users associated to an entity I would use:

```
/entity/1/users
```

Adding a user could be done by POSTing a user,

```
POST /entity/1/users
<User>
...
</User>
```

Deleting a user would be

```
DELETE /User/5
```

Updating or creating a user could be done with PUT

```
PUT /User/6
```

Removing the association between a user and an entity requires a bit of creativity.  You could do

```
DELETE /Entity/1/User/5
```

as you suggested, or something like

```
DELETE /Entity/1/UserLink?UserId=5
```

or just

```
DELETE /Entity/1/Users?UserId=5
```

It reality is not very important to the user of your API what your URI looks like.  It's good to be consistent for your own sanity, it is good to choose schemes that are easy to dispatch with your server framework, but it is not what your URIs look like, it is what you do with them that is important.

Comment: Thanks for all the approaches. I think your post is very helpful because it confirms that what I'm doing is correct then. For example, I do have /entity/1 and /user/5 for when I use them individually... I was just having trouble with the many-to-many collection case. As you said, for deletes, you are pretty much forced to do something like /entity/1/user/5. Since I know what the id is in advance... there's not much easier to do a post actually and I can keep my add/remove urls the same, which I think increases sanity ;) Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I use your method for parent/child entities, but for many-to-many I use an array in my JSON object representing that entity.

So using your example:

```
GET /entity/1
```

would return an entity object something like this:

```
{"entityID":1,"name":"whatever","users":[1,2,3,4,5]}
```

PUT would pass in this same object, and update both the entity and the users. Then to get the specific user info:

```
GET /users/3
```

Using PUT on users/3 would update the user. PUT on /entity/1 would connect users to entities. Unfortunately, there's not not a lot of good info out there on how to model this sort of thing.

Comment: Hrm... well I already have /entity/x and /user/x for the individual entities. Wouldn't your method be a tad inefficient? If I want to add a new user to an entity, I would have to get the current list of users, append one and then send the whole list back. That is really the standard way to do it? Sounds bizarre... but I guess I wouldn't put it past the people that write these standards ;)

Comment: No, it's not a standard, just something I came up with. Resolution tables are so simple and narrow that I have always just cleared and recreated the records whenever the parent entity was modified. The simplicity trumps inefficiency in my opinion. The only case where I wouldn't do this is if the same entity was going to be edited often enough to be relevant.