# What's the best way of implementing a many-to-many relationship, that contains meta, RESTfully?

Tags: http, rest, many-to-many, metadata

When representing data models through a RESTful interface it is understood to create top level endpoints that associate to a type/group of objects:

- /users
- /cars

We can re-use HTTP verbs to enable actions upon these groups (GET to list, POST to create, etc). And when representing a model with a "dependency" (being that it can't exist without a "parent"), we can create deeper endpoints to represent that dependency relationship:

- /users/[:id]/tokens

In this case, it makes sense to not have a top-level endpoint of `/tokens`, as they shouldn't be able to exist without the user.

Many-to-many relationships get a bit more tricky. If two models can have a many-to-many relationship but can also truly exist on their own, it makes sense to give both objects a top-level endpoint and a deeper endpoint for defining that relationship:

- /users
- /cars
- /users/[:id]/cars
- /cars/[:id]/users

We can then use **PUT** and **DELETE** methods to define those relationships through an HTTP interface: `PUT /users/[:user_id]/cars/[:car_id]`. It makes sense that running that **PUT** operation would create a data-model that somehow links the two objects (like a join table in a relational DB).

---

The tricky part, then, becomes deciding on where to limit the interface to combat redundancy.

Do you allow a **GET** request to the second-level deep endpoints (`GET /users/[:user_id]/cars/[:car_id]`)? Or do you require that they access the "car" from the top level `GET /cars/[:id]`?

### Now, what if the many-to-many relationship contains meta information? How do you represent that and where do you return it?

For example, what if we wanted to keep track of how many times a **user** drove a certain **car**? Where would we return that information? If we return it at the nested endpoint, are we violating REST or being inconsistent if we return the meta information and not the resource? Do we embed the meta information in the requested resource through an attribute of some kind?

Pls advise. :P (but really, thanks)

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4521452/what-is-the-proper-way-to-deal-with-adding-deleting-many-to-many-relationships-i?rq=1

Comment: @BrianKelly Thank you, but that doesn't answer the question of how to represent the returned model (meta vs resource and model embed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is really more of a personal design preference at this point IMHO.

I would personally opt for stopping at /users/[:user_id]/cars/ and then requiring a call to /cars/[:car_id] to get the car information.

If you are including relation specific metadata though, like "how many times a user drove a certain car?" it would make sense to keep that under a deeper relationship like /users/[:user_id]/cars/[:car_id].

Truthfully it's not an exact science.  You have to do what is simplest, most expressive, yet still powerful enough for your data model.

Comment: This is an awesome response. Thanks man. What do you think about the part of embedding the meta in the resource vs just returning the meta at the deep endpoint?

Comment: I'd vote for something dynamic like Jeremy Weiskotten suggests.  Maybe a /meta or /stats that dynamically changes based on the nesting.

Again though, this is more personal preference of design then a dogmatic REST spec.

Answer (score 3):

You could create a new resource. Something like `users/[:user_id]/cars/[:car_id]/stats`, whose response includes `{drivings_count: 123}`. You'd probably only allow a GET of this resource.

Comment: That's an interesting idea. Thanks!